# Confused by how many ways there are to set NODE_ENV

Tags: javascript, node.js, coding-style, environment-variables

I'm trying to set a flag that informs my code whether it is in production or development. So far I've seen:

In VS Code's `launch.json`:

```
{ "configurations": { "env": "NODE_ENV": "development" } }
```

In Node's `package.json`:

```
{ "scripts": { "start": "NODE_ENV=production" } }
```

In Webpack's `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = { "plugins": new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"' }) }
```

While running the code:

```
set NODE_ENV=production && node app
```

NPM packages:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/envify
```

Powershell:

```
$env:NODE_ENV="production"
```

I guess I'm just confused because by default I have around 4 of those set currently. How exactly do these interact? Are they all referring to the same variable? Should I only have one of these? Which ones overwrite the others?

I'd really prefer if there were just a single point to set this because it seems like every single module lets you specify it and as a result, I'm confused as to where it is actually being set. Also, is there anyway to access this flag on the client-side as well or is it server-side only?

Comment: setting `environment variable` seems good approach, and is independent of   packages, modules or IDEs.

Comment: @MukeshSharma: So would I just delete all of the other ones listed here? I think `React` needs the webpack one for it to run in production on client side.

Comment: yes, but, again `webpack` is setting `node` environment which runs on server. It has been discussed here as well. https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-boilerplate/issues/54

Comment: @ChronBag It looks like you are running on Windows considering the VS and Powershell references. Are you planning on running this in IISNode though? If so you'll actually set your `NODE_ENV` within your `Web.config`.

Comment: @peteb: I'm using Windows for development and Linux for production so that just adds more confusion.

Comment: @ChronBag how do you plan on running your app on Linux, `pm2`?

Comment: @peteb: Wasn't until just now (I'm still new) but after looking at it now, it seems like a good choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the scenario you've specified, the `NODE_ENV` environment variable will be initialized by the process that is actually executing your code. See the below excerpt from the [environment variable wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

> In all Unix and Unix-like systems, each process has its own separate set of environment variables. By default, when a process is created, it inherits a duplicate environment of its parent process, except for explicit changes made by the parent when it creates the child. At the API level, these changes must be done between running fork and exec. Alternatively, from command shells such as bash, a user can change environment variables for a particular command invocation by indirectly invoking it via env or using the `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=VALUE <command>` notation. All Unix operating system flavors, DOS, and Windows have environment variables; however, they do not all use the same variable names. A running program can access the values of environment variables for configuration purposes.

So if you were to run your code using `pm2`, then `pm2` will actually assign the `NODE_ENV` environment variable prior to executing your application. It uses a [JSON file for options](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#options) where you can specify your environment variables using the `env` property.

In short, all the ways to set your `NODE_ENV` are more or less equivalent, it just boils down to who starts your process.

Since environment variables are local to a machine (the *environment*) they are set locally and can't be set by a client.

Comment: So what you're saying is `pm2` will override all the other six flags so I might as well just delete them. Ok, thanks.

Comment: Like I said, it totally depends on which process is actually executing your app, that is the one that determines what the environment variables are set to

Comment: Yeah I meant if I used pm2. So, if I executed it with node then `{ "scripts": { "start": "NODE_ENV=production" } }` would win and if I executed it with VS Code then `{ "configurations": { "env": "NODE_ENV": "development" } }` would win, right?